# How to add mongodb to Snap app?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

Given this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    (conf, site, cleanup) <- $(loadSnapTH [| getConf |]
                                          'getActions
                                          ["snaplets/heist/templates"])


    _ <- try $ httpServe conf site :: IO (Either SomeException ())
    cleanup


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | This action loads the config used by this application. The loaded config
-- is returned as the first element of the tuple produced by the loadSnapTH
-- Splice. The type is not solidly fixed, though it must be an IO action that
-- produces the same type as 'getActions' takes. It also must be an instance of
-- Typeable. If the type of this is changed, a full recompile will be needed to
-- pick up the change, even in development mode.
--
-- This action is only run once, regardless of whether development or
-- production mode is in use.
getConf :: IO (Config Snap AppConfig)
getConf = commandLineConfig defaultConfig


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | This function generates the the site handler and cleanup action from the
-- configuration. In production mode, this action is only run once. In
-- development mode, this action is run whenever the application is reloaded.
--
-- Development mode also makes sure that the cleanup actions are run
-- appropriately before shutdown. The cleanup action returned from loadSnapTH
-- should still be used after the server has stopped handling requests, as the
-- cleanup actions are only automatically run when a reload is triggered.
--
-- This sample doesn't actually use the config passed in, but more
-- sophisticated code might.
getActions :: Config Snap AppConfig -> IO (Snap (), IO ())
getActions conf = do
    (msgs, site, cleanup) <- runSnaplet
        (appEnvironment =<< getOther conf) app
    hPutStrLn stderr $ T.unpack msgs
    return (site, cleanup)
```

where do I even *begin* if I want to add mongodb database functionality ([this nice example here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mongoDB/1.3.0/doc/html/Database-MongoDB.html))???

Snap has only two examples:

1. One really simple one (of no use here): http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/snap-api
2. And the one above, which is generated with snap (I already forgot how I generated it, and can't seem to find it in the docs?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can use package [snaplet-mongodb-minimalistic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snaplet-mongodb-minimalistic) and there is usage [example](https://github.com/Palmik/snaplet-mongodb-minimalistic/tree/master/examples/example1/src) on github.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! By the way, here is a fix for the example to make it work with snap 0.9 (in case anyone is interested): https://github.com/Palmik/snaplet-mongodb-minimalistic/pull/7